# Regex get text part between two words

Tags: php, regex

I need get all text between `Lorem` until the last occurrence of `CEP` code.
I'm just getting the first occurrence, but some paragraphs have two `CEP` codes.

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt CEP 142802/AA, mollit anim id est laborum CEP 13342802/AA.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt CEP 11123/AA

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt CEP 2223/AA
```

Se example working here:
https://regex101.com/r/eZ0yP4/2

Thanks!

Comment: Is the last CEP code always at the end of the paragraph?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use positive lookahead assertion like below.

```
(?s)Lorem.*?CEP \d+\/[A-B]{2}(?=\.?(?:\n\n|$))
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/eZ0yP4/8)

**OR**

```
(?s)Lorem(?:(?!\n\n).)*CEP \d+\/[A-B]{2}
```

`(?:(?!\n\n).)*` matches any character but not of `\n\n` zero or more times. `\n\n` represents a blank line. `(?s)` DOTALL modifier which makes dot in your regex to match even line breaks.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/eZ0yP4/7)

Comment: no, he enabled DOTALL mode. and the example contains `\n` char inbetween.

Comment: Yep, I want to get all paragraphs separately! You are the best! Sorry for my poor English :(

Answer (score 0):

```
Lorem.*CEP \d+\/[AB]{2}
```

Try this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/eZ0yP4/3